# Android downloading an image

Tags: android, android-imageview

Here i have stored an image by converting as string using 'base64 format' on my server,and i could able to display it in the same way on image view .But now i want download it to my sd card .I can see that some people downloading using 'URL'. But in my case there is no URL.I  just converted the image into string and stored and able to display it on imageview by reconverting it.

this is the way i reconverted the string into image

```
//getting string from server using json parsor
 String image=json_data.getString("img");
 txt.setText(u);
//converting string to image
 byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(p.getBytes(), 0);
  im = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  im.setImageBitmap(
          BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0,imageAsBytes.length));
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: i need to save it to my sd card

Answer (score 2):

Use Image Loader libraries instead of yours.

- https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
- https://github.com/bumptech/glide
- http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

**THIS SNIPPET SHOULD HELP !**

// give any name to file xxx.jpg

```
   File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/name.jpg"); 

   FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
```

**EDIT**

```
Bitmap x = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageasbytes , 0 , inageasbytes.length());

                    x.compress(
                            Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, os);

                        os.flush();
                        os.close();
```

Also , add the following permission .

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Also if you want to know how to recover it..

```
String imgFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/name.jpg"; 

Bitmap myBitmap =     BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile);
```

Imageview.setimagebitmap(mybitmap);

Comment: sorry it says cannot invoke compress on the array byte[] in your 3rd line

Comment: Sorry sir now getting the error un handled exception type file not found exception in the line 'File filepath=....'

Comment: Now now..don't call me sir I'm just 16

Comment: Replace it with the following

Comment: try { File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/name.jpg"); 
}catch(FileNotFoundException x){ x.printstacktrace();}

Comment: ok brother,i did the same but got nullpointer exception in logtcat and showing unfortunateley program has stopped in emulator

Comment: Does your logcat have an external storage defined ? ... Post the logcat here